# Swift: Autolayout programmatically results in wrong frame size (decimals)

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am trying to set up a 9:16 aspect view inside a container view. The following code sets the constraints in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` so that Autolayout can be considered at the right place. It also calls `layoutIfNeeded`.

While the calculation of `maxWidth` is correct (on an iPhone X: 609.7777777777778), the constraint which is set will create a wrong frame size (on an iPhone X: 609.6666666666666).

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var orangeContainerView: UIView!
    var inset: CGFloat = 16

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        setupAutolayout()
    }

    func setupAutolayout() {
        let aspectRatioView = UIView()
        aspectRatioView.backgroundColor = .blue
        orangeContainerView.addSubview(aspectRatioView)
        aspectRatioView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // Set up a 9:16 view
        // calculate max width, and based on that the max height and see if it fits into the container
        let maxWidth = orangeContainerView.frame.width - (2 * inset)
        let targetHeight = maxWidth / 9 * 16
        if targetHeight <= orangeContainerView.frame.height {
            print("FRAME SIZE SHOULD BE: \(maxWidth) x \(targetHeight)")
            aspectRatioView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: orangeContainerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
            aspectRatioView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: orangeContainerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            aspectRatioView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: maxWidth).isActive = true
            aspectRatioView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: targetHeight).isActive = true
        }

        orangeContainerView.layoutIfNeeded()
        print(aspectRatioView.frame)
    }

}
```

The prints are the following in iPhone X simulator:

```
FRAME SIZE SHOULD BE: 343.0 x 609.7777777777778
(16.0, 0.0, 343.0, 609.6666666666666)
```

A screenshot of the IB: [image: IB screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frame coordinates cannot be arbitrary.

If the device scale is 2 (such as an iPhone 8), frame boundaries will be rounded to 1/2 points.

If the device scale is 3 (such as an iPhone X), frame boundaries will be rounded to 1/3 points.

So, while your floating-point calculation results in `609.7777777777778`, setting that value as the width constraint will give you an actual frame width of:

- on an iPhone X: `609.6666666666666` (609 and 2/3)
- on an iPhone 8: `610.0`

Comment: That is disappointing. Why does Apple limit that? But this is only for autolayout? When I do the same calculation and set up the frame manually, it is correct. How comes?

Comment: Pretty much, yes... it is a characteristic of auto-layout. If you ***really*** want partial-pixels coordinates, you'll have to explicitly set them rather than using auto-layout.